# Запуск сайта на домашнем компьютере

Tags: хостинг, веб-сервер

Привет! Вот встал вопрос: планирую запустить небольшой сайт с посещаемостью около 50 человек в день (для начала). Запускать хочу на домашнем компьютере (сайт пишется на Java), он не особо мощный, оперативка маленькая 1 гигабайт. Сервером для сайта будет томкат. Так вот какой минимум для интернета нужен для сайта, просто особо быстрого интернета у нас тут не найдешь. С доменом все уже в порядке, он куплен, все готово, не хочется пользоваться услугами хостера, все хочу сделать сам. Для ОС хочу Ubuntu 10.10 поставить. В общем как думаете, правильно ли сделан выбор ОС, ну и какой интернет нужен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я как-то поднимал форум на 256 пентиуме с 200мегами памяти и интернетом в 64кбит.

Ос в принципе пойдет любая. Памяти должно хватить, для простого сайта гигабайт - невероятно много. Не знаю, сколько ест java, но тоже должно хватить. В вопросе про интернет главное, чтобы был доступ к твоему компу из интернета. Лучше взять статический ip, если провайдер позволяет. Скорость не так важна, если у тебя не 4килобита в секунду.

Кстати, на досуге можешь посчитать, сколько электричества съест постоянно работающий комп.

Comment: хорошо замечено на счет электричества! Сейчас же полным-полно хостингов с бесплатным размещением! Зачем так извращаться?

Comment: Just for lulz же. Ничто так не способствует навыкам системного администрирования, как собственноручно поднятый, уроненный и восстановленный сервер.

Comment: Замучаетесь ронять, никому не нужный сайт с малой посещаемостью.